# grouping data by year in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a csv file containing data starting from 2006/01/01 to 2011/01/01 , it contains: ( timestapm, heure, lat, lon, impact) and i need to calculate the average of impacts per month over years and then plot it.
i believe i should group data daily , then monthly, then by year.

here's a sample of my data :

```
 timestamp,heure,lat,lon,impact,type
 2007-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
 2007-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
 2007-01-02 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
 2007-01-03 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
 2007-01-03 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

and here's the code i am using :

```
names =["timestamp","heure","lat","lon","impact","type"]
data = pd.read_csv('flash.txt', names=names, parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col=['timestamp'])
print (data.head())
daily = data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D'))['impact'].count()
monthly = daily.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))['impact'].count()
ax = yearly.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

And here's the result i am getting :
[image]

SO, my main request, is how to group by year in order to have ( january of first year in the file until january of last year in the file gathered in one bar) and so on for all the months.
any ideas ?

Comment: The answer to your question sounds like the groupby month you are applying in line 5. Or do you want something else?

Comment: this is a group by month, i need a group by year

Comment: oh wait, I got confused: you want by year and month, right?

Comment: yes exactly , i need to group by year what i grouped by month, in order to have all the months of (for example : january of the 6 years ) in one bar and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a groupby combination:
(assuming that you have an index of time datetime)

```
data.groupby([(data.index.year),(data.index.month)])['impact'].count()
```

This will group by year and by month

Comment: i did as you said, and i got this error : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'month'

Comment: Is your index a datetime index? (check with: data.index.dtype_str)

Comment: i checked and i got this : datetime64[ns]

Comment: There should be no reason why this is not working. Can you share your code snippet + a piece of your data? You can use something like https://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: it's my bad, it's working now fine ...thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it:

```
data.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)).size()
```

Similarly:

```
df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).size()
```